# How to create a simple "four area graph" in excel or google sheets?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, charts

From a very basic dataset, I need to create this graph, but I'm struggling. Is there a simple way to achieve this in Excel or Google Sheets? Thank you.

[image: My Data]

[image: My Graph]

Comment: This question would be better suited to Superuser. That said, do you want to just colour cells as in your example? if yes, conditional formatting could do what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Sheets, you can create the desired chart using 'Area Chart' and a little bit of maths. You need to calculate the three Cartesian coordinates for the non-origin corners of each respective area (obviously they all have a corner at 0,0); assuming the values in your table correspond to the area of the square for each category, the sides of the squares are therefore of length √(area). The coordinates need to be formatted like this:

| x | seqv | seqnv | simv | simnv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -3.464101615 | 0 |  |  |  |
| -3.464101615 | 3.464101615 |  |  |  |
| 0 | 3.464101615 |  |  |  |
| 0 |  | 5 |  |  |
| 5 |  | 5 |  |  |
| 5 |  | 0 |  |  |
| -5.830951895 |  |  | 0 |  |
| -5.830951895 |  |  | -5.830951895 |  |
| 0 |  |  | -5.830951895 |  |
| 4.69041576 |  |  |  | -4.69041576 |
| 4.69041576 |  |  |  | -4.69041576 |
| 0 |  |  |  | -4.69041576 |

The subsequent chart will look something like this (I have removed the edge lines):
[image]